# If Multiple Find Conditions match then ... in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have Input and Output tabs.

In Input Tab I have my headers on Column B and sub-headers on Column C as shown below:

```
 A   B       C       D      
    HDR1
           SB1.1     Data1
           SB2.1     Data2
    HDR2
           SB2.1     Data3
           SB2.2     Data4
           SB2.3     Data5
```

And in Output Tab I have my full list as shown below:

```
 A   B       C       D      
    HDR1   SB1.1
    HDR1   SB2.1     

    HDR2   SB2.1     
    HDR2   SB2.2     
    HDR2   SB2.3
```

I need to search for Header and all of it's Sub-Headers respectively.

For example: Search for Input HDR1 in Output Column B but also search for Input SB1.1 in same row number's column C. If find, than copy Input Data to Output Data column. If not, search for second Subheader (which is SB2.1) in column C in this example.

The thing here is I don't know how many sub-headers any header has. It might be 1 or 5. That is still ok I created my loops for this. My question is: how can I add multiple find conditions within this loop.

```
Sub Macro1()

'Call screenupdatingfalse
Dim wsO As Worksheet, wsI As Worksheet
Set wsI = Sheet2 'wsI is Input Sheet
Set wsO = Sheet1 'wsO is Output sheet
Dim RowLastB As Long, rowlastC As Long, FirstBcellRow As Long, FirstBcellText As String, OutputNewRowQty As Long, i As Long, x As Long, beginBcol As Long
```

> 'Below I am finding last rows of the Input sheet to define the end of my loops.

```
    RowLastB = wsI.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    rowlastC = wsI.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
```

> 'Below I am starting my loops with the First Header in Column B. Then Finding next Header, then looking for how many sub-headers each header has.

```
beginBcol = 1
For i = beginBcol To RowLastB
wsI.Activate
FirstBcellRow = wsI.Range("B" & i).End(xlDown).Row
FirstBcellText = wsI.Range("B" & i).End(xlDown).Text

'FirstCcellRow = wsI.Range("C" & i).End(xlDown).Row


StartCopyRow = FirstBcellRow

i = FirstBcellRow
If i = RowLastB Then
OutputNewRowQty = (rowlastC - RowLastB)
Exit For
Else
SecondBcellRow = wsI.Range("B" & i).End(xlDown).Row
OutputNewRowQty = (SecondBcellRow - FirstBcellRow) - 1
'that amount of row to be added to Output

wsO.Activate
wsO.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo below
```

> My Question is this part: How can I create the right Find loop. This part eats my brain and I couldn't find the right answer anywhere on the internet even in SO!!

```
Set Brange = wsO.Range("F").Find(FirstBcellText, , xlValues, xlWhole)
Set cRange = wsO.Range("G").Find(wsI.Range(", , xlValues, xlWhole)

OutputRowNo = ActiveCell.Row

x = 1
Do Until x = OutputNewRowQty + 1
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
x = x + 1
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Loop

copyloop = 1
Do Until copyloop = OutputNewRowQty + 1

InputCopyCell = (StartCopyRow + 1)
wsI.Range("A" & InputCopyCell).Copy
wsO.Range("I" & (OutputRowNo + 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

wsI.Range("C" & InputCopyCell).Copy
wsO.Range("J" & (OutputRowNo + 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

wsI.Range("L" & InputCopyCell).Copy
wsO.Range("K" & (OutputRowNo + 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
wsO.Range("K" & (OutputRowNo + 1)).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"

copyloop = copyloop + 1
StartCopyRow = StartCopyRow + 1
OutputRowNo = OutputRowNo + 1
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Loop

beginBcol = FirstBcellRow
End If
below:
Next
'Call screenupdatingon

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably could use something like below.

```
Public Sub demo()
Dim wksInp As Worksheet: Set wksInp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")
Dim wksOut As Worksheet: Set wksOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")
Dim lngLastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim rgRef As Range

'\\ Find Last Row on output sheet
lngLastRow = wksOut.Range("B" & wksOut.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lngLastRow
    If Len(wksOut.Range("B" & i).Value) > 0 Then '\\ Check Non-Blank Cell in Column B
        '\\ See if the range exists in Input sheet
        Set rgRef = wksInp.Range("B:B").Find(wksOut.Range("B" & i).Value, , , xlWhole)
        If Not rgRef Is Nothing Then
            '\\ Now that we have found a suitable range in column B lets loop through all sub-headings in col c.
            j = 0
            Do While wksInp.Cells(rgRef.Row + 1 + j, rgRef.Column).Value = ""
                If rgRef.Offset(1 + j, 1).Value = wksOut.Range("C" & i).Value Then
                    wksOut.Range("D" & i).Value = rgRef.Offset(1 + j, 2).Value
                    Exit Do '\\Match found so we exit Do loop
                End If
                j = j + 1
            Loop
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying to implement it and will let you know as soon as I could give it a go. Thanks